# Apply function to column before filtering

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a column in my database called `coordinates`, now the coordinates column contains information on the range of time an object takes up within my graph. I want to allow the user to filter by the date, but the problem is I use a function to determine the date normally. Take:

```
# query_result is the result of some filter operation
for obj in query_result:
    time_range, altitude_range = get_shape_range(obj.coordinates)
    # time range for example would be "2006-06-01 07:56:17 - ..."
```

Now if I wanted to filter by date, I would want to is a `like`:

```
query_result = query_result.filter(
    DatabaseShape.coordinates.like('%%%s%%' % date))
```

But the problem is I first need to apply `get_shape_range` to `coordinates` in order to receive a string. Is there any way to do ... I guess a transform_filter operation? Such that before the `like` happens, I apply some function to coordinates? In this case I would need to write a `get_time_range` function that returned only time, but the question remains the same.

---

EDIT: Here's my database class

```
class DatabasePolygon(dbBase):
    __tablename__ = 'objects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)  # primary key
    tag = Column(String)  # shape tag
    color = Column(String)  # color of polygon
    time_ = Column(String)  # time object was exported
    hdf = Column(String)  # filename
    plot = Column(String)  # type of plot drawn on
    attributes = Column(String)  # list of object attributes
    coordinates = Column(String)  # plot coordinates for displaying to user
    notes = Column(String)  # shape notes
    lat = Column(String)

    @staticmethod
    def plot_string(i):
        return constants.PLOTS[i]

    def __repr__(self):
        """
        Represent the database class as a JSON object. Useful as our program
        already supports JSON reading, so simply parse out the database as
        separate JSON 'files'
        """
        data = {}
        for key in constants.plot_type_enum:
            data[key] = {}
        data[self.plot] = {self.tag: {
            'color': self.color,
            'attributes': self.attributes,
            'id': self.id,
            'coordinates': self.coordinates,
            'lat': self.lat,
            'notes': self.notes}}
        data['time'] = self.time_
        data['hdfFile'] = self.hdf
        logger.info('Converting unicode to ASCII')
        return byteify(json.dumps(data))
```

and I'm using sqlite 3.0. The reasoning why behind most things are strings is because most of my values that are to be stored in the database are sent as strings, so storing is trivial. I'm wondering if I should do all this parsing magic with the functions *before*, and just have more database entries? for stuff like decimal *time_begin*, *time_end*, *latitude_begin* instead of having a string containing the range of *time* that I parse to find *time_begin* and *time_end* when i'm filtering

Comment: I think the best way would be to make coordinate as class and make it as an element of database,there you can add methods you want on coordinates without calling changing database like DatabaseShape.coordinates.get_shape_range

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan , if I made a class an element of my database, i'd be able to do something like `DatabaseShape.coordinates.get_shape_range.like('date')`? But wouldn't get_shape_range return a string in my case, so you can't just use a `.like` on it?

Comment: Which database are you using? What does the contents of `coordinates` look like, is it a string?

Comment: You are trying to do the database's job - filter the "query_result". I would let the DB does it job for you. Do the filtering on the DB side. What kind of DB are you using? And can you shed some light on a table structure? With a proper data model it would be rather easy.

Comment: In my opinion you cant have both at the same time,first you need get all objects filtered by date as a list and loop through them to get the shape range supposing that all objects in query results have coordinates,i have no knowledge about sqlalchemy but i can i assume it supports lambda functions

Comment: See edit for more information if needed

Comment: @SyntacticFructose - can you share an example of the coordinates field? That may change my thinking, but my strong recommendation echoes the others: bite the bullet and break the `coordinates` string into multiple, typed fields (perhaps using a class/mixin). You said "storing is trivial". True. But does your code store more often, or read more often? Similarly, which requires more flexibility, reading or writing? Relational databases (even SQLite) do an insanely good job of supporting different predicates, transformations, etc.

Comment: "The reasoning why behind most things are strings is because most of my values that are to be stored in the database are sent as strings, so storing is trivial."  Putting thought into how you structure your data for analytical purposes is not a trivial exercise, as you're finding out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should definitely parse strings to columns before storing it in the databases. Let the database do the job it was designed for!

```
CREATE TABLE [coordinates]
(
  id                INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  tag               VARCHAR2(32),
  color             VARCHAR2(32)    default 'green',
  time_begin        TIMESTAMP,
  time_end          TIMESTAMP,
  latitude_begin    INT
);

create index ix_coord_tag on coordinates(tag);
create index ix_coord_tm_beg on coordinates(time_begin);

insert into coordinates(tag, time_begin, time_end, latitude_begin)
values('tag1', '2006-06-01T07:56:17', '2006-06-01T07:56:19', 123);

insert into coordinates(tag, time_begin, time_end, latitude_begin)
values('tag1', '2016-01-01T11:35:01', '2016-01-01T12:00:00', 130);

insert into coordinates(tag, color, time_begin, time_end, latitude_begin)
values('tag2', 'blue', '2014-03-03T20:11:01', '2014-03-03T20:11:20', 2500);

insert into coordinates(tag, color, time_begin, time_end, latitude_begin)
values('tag2', 'blue', '2014-03-12T23:59:59', '2014-03-13T00:00:29', 2978);

insert into coordinates(tag, color, time_begin, time_end, latitude_begin)
values('tag3', 'red', '2016-01-01T11:35:01', '2016-01-01T12:00:00', 13000);

insert into coordinates(tag, color, time_begin, time_end, latitude_begin)
values('tag3', 'red', '2016-01-01T12:00:00', '2016-01-01T12:00:11', 13001);

.headers on
.mode column

select * from coordinates where tag='tag1' and '2006-06-01T07:56:18' between time_begin and time_end;

select * from coordinates where color='blue' and time_end between '2014-03-13T00:00:00' and '2014-03-13T00:10:00';
```

Output:

```
sqlite> select * from coordinates where tag='tag1' and '2006-06-01T07:56:18' between time_begin and time_end;
id          tag         color       time_begin           time_end             latitude_begin
----------  ----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------
1           tag1        green       2006-06-01T07:56:17  2006-06-01T07:56:19  123
sqlite>
sqlite> select * from coordinates where color='blue' and time_end between '2014-03-13T00:00:00' and '2014-03-13T00:10:00';
id          tag         color       time_begin           time_end             latitude_begin
----------  ----------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------  --------------
4           tag2        blue        2014-03-12T23:59:59  2014-03-13T00:00:29  2978
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the title of the question, I assume that you aren't set on using the `like()` method.

SQLAlchemy's [`Query.filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) will accept any criteria that evaluates to a boolean.

Why not modify your filter criterion, so that instead of using the `like()` method on a string, you are testing on Python `datetime.date` objects?

I don't knowing what `obj.coordinates` looks like, but here's a rough outline that I hope make sense:

```
def check_range(coords, date):
    """ takes a date, and a "coordinates" value (representing a date 
        range), and a date as inputs, returns True if the 
        date is within that date range, else returns False
    """
    #some code here...


query_result = query_result.filter(
        check_range(DatabaseShape.coordinates, date)
    )
```